# Exclude three ID's from MySQL query

Tags: mysql, wordpress

can anyone help with this query?

I have this default query below and need to EXCLUDE 3 IDs from results (5707, 5782, 5755) and i can't guess ho to add NOT IN inside this query structure. Please help!

```
        $agents_query = array(
            'post_type'      => 'agent',
            'posts_per_page' => $number_of_posts,
            'paged'          => $paged,
            'orderby'        => 'rand',
        );

        $agents_query        = inspiry_agents_sort_args( $agents_query );
        $agent_listing_query = new WP_Query( $agents_query );
```

Comment: see if this helps you https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65146/exclude-post-id-from-wp-query

Comment: Yes, it has helped a lot. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
$agents_query = array(
    'post_type'      => 'agent',
    'post__not_in'   => array(5707,5782,5755),
    'posts_per_page' => $number_of_posts,
    'paged'          => $paged,
    'orderby'        => 'rand',
);

$agents_query        = inspiry_agents_sort_args( $agents_query );
$agent_listing_query = new WP_Query( $agents_query );
```